# Read the large document using marklogic Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I am trying to read xml/json documents using Node.js from MarkLogic. I have downloaded Node.js API code base from the following URL.

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api

It's working fine for small documents like 500KB. But our requirement is to read large documents, like 2 MB or 10 MB.

Regarding this, we have two cases, as mentioned below:-

Case 1:- Whenever I am trying to read a document using MarkLogic Node.js API,I should get more than one chunk, but I got only one chunk as response. So for this reason it is not working.

```
var chunks = 0;
var length = 0;
db.documents.read("test.xml").stream('chunked').
  on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
    console.log(chunk.length);
    chunks++;
    length += chunk.length;
  }).
  on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }).
  on('end', function() {
    console.log('read '+chunks+' chunks of '+length+' length');
    console.log('done');
  });
```

Case 2:- Whenever I am trying to read some large document( like 2 MB or 10 MB) using "http-digest-client" package then it is working fine and I get complete xml as response.

```
var digest = require('http-digest-client')('<Username>', '<password>');
digest.request({
  host: '<Host server>',
  path: '/v1/documents?uri=test.xml',
  port: 8007,
  method: 'GET',
}, function (res) {
  reply(res);
});
```

I have tested this with large document in the below mentioned example (please refer below url), but I get the same response which I have described in case 1  above.

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/develop/examples/read-stream.js#L27

As per my requirement, I would like to read the large document using MarkLogic Node.js API (Case 1).

1. How can I read a large document using MarkLogic Node.js API?
2. Is there any option to increase pool memory size or any other memory size?
3. Is this issue related memory size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the code example.  I'm able to reproduce the problem.

Please file an issue against the MarkLogic Node.js API at:

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/issues

Comment: Fixed for 8.0-3; that said, the best practice for MarkLogic is to work with much smaller documents.  (Think of the document as a row and the collection as a table.)  https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/commit/4d5a82152d34d8147bc423cd9dce74b1281d51c1

Comment: Thanks ehennum. Its working fine. Once again thanks :)